# Is there a way to print array in order with entries entered in that [TCL]

Tags: tcl

I have an array in Tcl, say

```
set count(a) b
set count(b) b
set count(c) b
set count(e) b
set count(d) b
set count(z) b
set count(m) b
```

When I print this I get output

```
array names count

d m e a z b c
```

Is there a way I can get the same order in which I have written the array?

Comment: I've removed your tag and reference to Perl. I could explain how to keep Perl hash elements in order, but it would be irrelevant to a Tcl application

Comment: I know perl too. If you can tell me in perl then I can convert this in TCL unless you are not using some direct method in PERL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `dict` instead (mostly the same thing, just another syntax):

```
dict set count a b
dict set count b b
dict set count c b
dict set count e b
dict set count d b
dict set count z b
dict set count m b
```

The following prints the keys in insertion order

```
% dict keys $count
a b c e d z m
```

If you want to have it both ways, assign to the dictionary and recreate an array when desired using

```
array unset countArray
array set countArray $count
```

`dict` was added in Tcl 8.5. While an `array` never preserves insertion order for its elements, original insertion order is kept for `dict` elements even after later assignments.

Dictionaries and arrays are both implemented as hash tables and have some overlap in functionality. However, arrays are primarily containers for variables and allow elements to be individually traced. Dictionaries are containers of values, and can be interchanged with other kinds of data (the `dict` command ensemble can only use even-sized proper lists).

Documentation: [array](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/array.htm), [dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Based on [the Tcl wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1032) you can't do it

> Array keys are not ordered. It isn't straight-forward to get values out of an array in the same order that they were set. One common alternative is to get the names and then order them. In contrast, values in a dict are ordered.

Comment: *"In contrast, values in a dict are ordered"* Interesting. That's the opposite way round from what I would expect

Comment: it looks so from my test. haven't paid attention to key order till now. perhaps lists are better way if the order is an important concern.

Answer (score 1):

### dict in tcl8.5 is recommended. This is how you can do it with an array though:

```
array set foo {}
set fooOrder [list]

trace variable foo w bar

proc bar {args} {
    global fooOrder
    lappend fooOrder [lindex $args 1]
}

set foo(a) 10
set foo(c) 20
set foo(b) 30

puts "Default behaviour..."
puts [parray foo]

puts "Maintaining the order..."
foreach key $fooOrder {
    puts "foo($key) = $foo($key)"
}
```

---

### Output:

```
sharad@ss:~$ tclsh my.tcl
Default behaviour...
foo(a) = 10
foo(b) = 30
foo(c) = 20

Maintaining the order...
foo(a) = 10
foo(c) = 20
foo(b) = 30
sharad@ss:~$
```

Comment: Nice! However, your `bar` proc ought to be a little more complicated. As written, consider the effect of `incr foo(a)`.